# Probability puzzle on Inference.

Tags: probability, puzzle

Couple of months ago, i was asked this weird probability puzzle in an interview.

Problem: There are two persons X and Y. Given a statement, X says it is true w.p $\frac{1}{3}$. and false w.p. $\frac{2}{3}$. Y always agrees with whatever X says.
What is the probability that the statement is actually true?

A seemingly related question is [Truth or Lie?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694647/truth-or-lie-probability)

Please help with a proper explanation. Does the information provided in the question sufficient to infer anything?

Comment: This is not clear.  Why do we care what $X$ says?  We are given no way to gauge $X's$ accuracy.  And $Y$ appears to serve no role at all.  Note:  the linked question is quite different as we are told how accurate the speakers are.

Comment: Exactly, this was asked in my goldman sachs interview. The interviewer said it can actually be solved.

Comment: Not quite sure how to interpret the question...I don't know what it means by ''$X$ says *a* given statement is true w.p. $1/3$ and false w.p. $1/4$''. Does $X$'s response depend at all on whether or not the statement is true or false? If not, what does $X$ do the other 1-1/3-1/4 of the time?

Comment: Perhaps the interviewer asked it incorrectly!

Comment: @lulu I was wondering if the question is reframed in terms of the linked question. i.e. probability of X making a true statement being 1/3. Can it be answered without knowing the probability of Y making a true statement.

Comment: We still need a prior for the truth of the statement.  If, say, you start from assumption that the statement is true with probability $\frac 12$ you can then use Bayes' Theorem  In this case, $Y$ is still irrelevant, of course.

Comment: Obviously the opinion of $X$ plays no role, as he does not check if the statement is true. The same concerns the opinion of $Y$.

Comment: @sarat If you have an edited question in mind, then please edit the actual body of the question so that it reflects what you would like to ask.

Comment: @T_M I dont have one. I recorded this question right after the interview .The question reflects his words verbatim. But after reading through the linked question i started wondering if the interviewer meant something else and asked incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, it should be clear that it is unanswerable.

Let $P$ be a statement. Suppose that it is true. What happens? $X$ will tell you it's true with probability $1/3$ and false with probability $2/3$. $Y$ will agree.

Let $P$ be a statement. Suppose that it is false. What happens? $X$ will tell you it's true with probability $1/3$ and false with probability $2/3$. $Y$ will agree.

You're given the same information in both situations. What $X$ tells you is independent of the truth or falsehood of the statement.

Assuming you're not missing any part of the question, I would speculate that the following is what your interviewer was getting at. Sometimes in ML, you will find yourself in a situation where your model has been trained in a way that its predictions become independent of your input data. Think for example about training on a dataset with very imbalanced class ratios-- maybe even only on one label. Would this be detectable? How would one figure out it was happening? Perhaps the interviewer wanted to lead into this sort of discussion.